# Regexp match all between parenthesis.

Tags: regex

I have the following snippet of text:

```
@article{carr2006,
  title={Techniques for qualitative and quantitative measurement of aspects of laser-induced damage important for laser beam propagation},
  author={Carr, CW and Feit, MD and Nostrand, MC and Adams, JJ},
  journal={Meas. Sci. Technol.},
  volume={17},
  number={7},
  pages={1958},
  year={2006},
  publisher={IOP Publishing}
}

@article{NIF1998,
author = {Schwartz, Sheldon and Feit, Michael D. and Kozlowski, Mark R. and Mouser, Ron P.},
title = {Current 3-ω large optic test procedures and data analysis for the quality assurance of National Ignition Facility optics},
journal = {Proc. SPIE},
volume = {3578},
number = {},
pages = {314-321},
year = {1999},
}
```

And I've been trying to extract the article by it's tag, however I fail to understand how the greedy/non-greedy works, or rather how to capture everything in the brackets when it contains more brackets :/

The following regexp returns a result up until first brackets, which is not what I'm aiming for...

```
/\{(carr2006[^}]+)\}?/s
```

Also was trying to capture full text with @article in front, but that doesn't work either...

```
/@*\{(carr2006[^}]+)\}?/s
```

Any explanations on what I'm doing wrong would be helpful :)

Comment: the second part with capturing @article in front was solved with @\w+ :)

Answer (score 1):

You may change your regex like below.

```
@\w+\{1st_standard(?:,\s*\w+\s*=\s*(?:{[^}]*}|"[^"]*"))+,?\s*\}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eO7bP1/3)

`\s*` should match any type of whitespace character so this would match also the line breaks.

Comment: However now it fails to capture any articles that don't have multiple brackets inside, like:
`@article{1st_standard,
title = "International standard test method for laser-induced damage threshold of optical surfaces",
journal = "24th Annual Boulder Damage Symposium Proceedings - Laser Induced Damage in Optical Materials: 1992",
volume = "1848",
number = "",
pages = "2-3",
year = "1993",
author = "Seitel, Steven C. and Giesen, Adolf and Becker, J.",
}`